# Парсинг колонки таблицы

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Не подскажете, как спарсить колонку Bitcoinprice таблицы с сайта [MYIP.MS](https://ru.myip.ms/browse/market_bitcoin/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD.html#a)?
Спарсить всю страницу могу, а вот как конкретную колонку таблицы не понимаю.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
site= "https://ru.myip.ms/browse/market_bitcoin/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD.html#a"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

UPD. Разобрался с таблицей, но как можно спарсить остальные страницы таблицы, а не только 1ую?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это возможно сделать через `BeautifulSoup`, но гораздо проще будет сделать это через `pandas` и [`.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) метод, парся таблицу напрямую в `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


site = "https://ru.myip.ms/browse/market_bitcoin/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD.html#a"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)

df = pd.read_html(page.read(), attrs={"id": "market_bitcoin_tbl"})[0]
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip()) # remove extra newlines from the column names
print(df['Bitcoin Price'])
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение получше моего выглядит) А что насчет других страниц таблицы? Не знаете как можно спарсить страницы помимо 1ой?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz оу, кстати, там этот HTML в пагинации отдается аяксом - например: https://ru.myip.ms/ajax_table/market_bitcoin/2 для второй страницы. Можно открыть бесконечный цикл, инкрементируя номер страницы до тех пор пока в ответе не будет данных. В цикле можно просто парсать тем же `read_html()` и добавлять новый датафрейм в существующий. Что-то вроде этого, я думаю. Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: При переходе по ссылке выдает - Ошибка загрузки данных! Пожалуйста, перезагрузите страницу! Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz ой да, забыл сказать, что туда нужно делать POST.

Comment: А вы бы не могли показать на примере? А то что-то до меня совсем не доходит

Comment: @Ayurpwnz конечно, пример кода в отдельном ответе, надеюсь поможет разобраться и узнать что-то новое.

Comment: `pd.read_html` умеет сам читать данные по ссылкам - `df = pd.read_html(site, attrs={"id": "market_bitcoin_tbl"})[0]`, при этом не понадобится "чистить" имена столбцов ;-)

Comment: @MaxU о, точно, спасибо, Макс, и с Новым Годом!

Answer (score 2):

Что касается Вашей второй проблемы, следовать пагинации мы можем эмулируя XHR POST запросы, попутно сохраняя данные в датафрейм. Что-то вроде вот такого:

```
from time import sleep

import pandas as pd
import requests


host = 'ru.myip.ms'
index_url = 'https://ru.myip.ms'
home_url = "https://ru.myip.ms/browse/market_bitcoin/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD.html#a"
base_ajax_url = "https://ru.myip.ms/ajax_table/market_bitcoin/{page}"


with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
        'Host': host
    }

    # visit home page and parse the initial dataframe
    response = session.get(home_url)

    df = pd.read_html(response.text, attrs={"id": "market_bitcoin_tbl"})[0]
    df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())  # remove extra newlines from the column names

    sleep(2)

    # start paginating with page=2
    page = 2
    while True:
        url = base_ajax_url.format(page=page)
        print("Processing {url}...".format(url=url))

        response = session.post(url,
                                data={'getpage': 'yes', 'lang': 'ru'},
                                headers={
                                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                                    'Origin': index_url,
                                    'Referer': home_url
                                })

        # add data to the existing dataframe
        try:
            new_df = pd.read_html("<table>{0}</table>".format(response.text))[0]
        except ValueError:  # could not extract data from HTML - last page?
            break

        new_df.columns = df.columns
        df = pd.concat([df, new_df])

        page += 1
        sleep(1)


print(df)
```

В пагинации на этой странице больше 4700 страниц, поэтому я не стал проверять все от начала до конца, но код работает для меня на нескольких страницах.

Обратите внимание на следующие вещи:

- использую `requests` и [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) для удобного менеджмента веб-скрейпинг сессии
- подобавлял тут и там искусственные задержки между реквестами, см. [How to be a good citizen when crawling web sites?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/91760/88474)
- в качестве условия выхода из цикла мы используем факт того, что `pandas` не может распарсать данные, когда мы достигаем страницы без данных, а только с текстом ошибки - возможно есть получше способ выйти из цикла - например, можно заранее отпарсать кол-во страниц и использовать обычный `for` цикл

Comment: Попробовал 20 страниц(с 1 по 20), везде выдает No tables found

Comment: @Ayurpwnz у меня было что-то подобное пока я не сменил айпи - наверное, у них есть rate limiting, но точно не уверен. Попробуйте немного позже попробовать или с другого айпи.

Comment: попробовал через прокси, но проблема в отм, что цена не отображается, вот что выдает `     №         ...                    Time GMT
0    1         ...          31 Dec 2018, 13:20
1    2         ...          31 Dec 2018, 13:10
2    3         ...          31 Dec 2018, 13:00
3    4         ...          31 Dec 2018, 12:50
4    5         ...          31 Dec 2018, 12:40
5    6         ...          31 Dec 2018, 12:30
6    7         ...          31 Dec 2018, 12:20
7    8         ...          31 Dec 2018, 12:10
8    9         ...          31 Dec 2018, 12:00`

Comment: Вместо точек по идее должна быть цена, но её не отображает

Comment: Не знаете почему так?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz а это точно не проблема вывода данных в датафрейме? Попробуйте только колонку с ценами посмотреть `print(df['Bitcoin Price'])`.